# Getting null from server when using SignalR in Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to integrate signaR in android, and I have integrated successfully also but I am getting null in proxy.on() method.

Here is my SignarService Class`

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {

private HubConnection connection;
private HubProxy proxy;
Context context;
private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // Binder given to clients

public SignalRService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startSignalR();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    connection.stop();
    connection = null;
    proxy = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Return the communication channel to the service.
    startSignalR();
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SignalRService getService() {
        return SignalRService.this;
    }
}

/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */
public void sendMessage(UserInfo info) {
    try {
        proxy.invoke("SendToSpecific", info).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startSignalR() {
    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

    String server = "http://74.208.44.96:8734/";
    connection = new HubConnection(server);

    proxy = connection.createHubProxy("SignalRChatHub");
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = connection.start(clientTransport);
    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String connectionId = connection.getConnectionId();
    System.out.println("Connection id is " + connection.getConnectionData() + " \n" + connection.getConnectionToken() + " \n" +
            connectionId);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String userID = preferences.getString(Config.USER_ID, null);
    String userName = preferences.getString(Config.USER_NAME, null);


    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
    info.setUserId(userID);
    info.setUserName(userName);
    info.setHubId(connectionId);

    try {
        proxy.invoke("Notify", info).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Then call on() to handle the messages when they are received.
    proxy.on("ObjBroadCastMessage", new SubscriptionHandler1<UserInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void run(UserInfo msg) {

            final String finalMsg = msg.getMessage() + "\nCall Status " + msg.getCallStatus() + "\n" +
                    "Profile Pic " + msg.getSubscriberToken() + "\nHub Id  " + msg.getHubId() + "\nName" +
                    msg.getIsFirstTime() + "\nIs First time " + msg.getIsFirstTime();
            // display Toast message
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
            , UserInfo.class);
}
```

}

Now when I connect to hub connection and send to request at server then my proxy.on() method called and server is sending object of Userinfo . But I am getting null in the UserInfo class object.
Here is my server side code

```
  class Program
{
    //static string url = "http://localhost:6899";
    static string url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"].ToString();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Add the SignalR Middlewware to the OWIN pipeline            
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

[HubName("SignalRChatHub")]
public class SignalRChatHub : Hub
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserDetail> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserDetail>();
    public void BroadCastMessage(String msgFrom, String msg)
    {            
        Clients.All.receiveMessage(msgFrom, msg);
    }

    public void ObjBroadCastMessage(UserInfo args)
    {            
        Clients.All.receiveMessage(args);
    }

    [HubMethodName("SendToSpecific")]
    public void SendToSpecific(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        if (userInfo.IsVideoCall)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInfo.PublisherSessionId))
            {
                OpenTok objOpenTok = new OpenTok(Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenTockAPIKey"]), WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenTockSecret"].ToString());

                double inOneWeek = (DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

                userInfo.SubscriberToken = objOpenTok.GenerateToken(userInfo.PublisherSessionId, Role.MODERATOR, inOneWeek, null);
            }

            if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
            {
                int uId;
                int TouId;
                bool userIdValid = int.TryParse(userInfo.UserId, out uId);
                bool TouserIdValid = int.TryParse(userInfo.UserId, out TouId);
                if (userInfo.CallStatus == "7")
                {
                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.UserId)))
                        dic[userInfo.UserId].CallStatus = "0";                        

                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                    {
                        dic[userInfo.ToUserId].CallStatus = "7";
                        Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
                    }

                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                        dic[userInfo.ToUserId].CallStatus = "0";
                }
                else if (userInfo.CallStatus == "5")
                {                        
                    if (userInfo.CallStatus == "5" && dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.UserId)))
                        dic[userInfo.UserId].CallStatus = "0";

                    if (userInfo.CallStatus == "5" && dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                        dic[userInfo.ToUserId].CallStatus = "0";

                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                        Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
                }
                else if (userInfo.CallStatus == "6")
                {
                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                        Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
                }
                else if (dic[userInfo.ToUserId].CallStatus == "1")
                {
                    userInfo.CallStatus = "3";
                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.UserId)))
                        Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.UserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
                }
                else if (userInfo.CallStatus == "1" || userInfo.CallStatus == "2")
                {
                    if (userInfo.CallStatus == "1" && dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.UserId)))
                        dic[userInfo.UserId].CallStatus = "1";

                    if (userInfo.CallStatus == "1" && dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                        dic[userInfo.ToUserId].CallStatus = "1";

                    if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                        Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
                }
                else if (userInfo.CallStatus == "0" && dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                {
                    dic[userInfo.ToUserId].CallStatus = userInfo.CallStatus;
                    Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
                }                    
            }
            else if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.UserId)))
            {
                userInfo.CallStatus = "4";
                Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.UserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);
            }
        }
        else
            if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
                Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);            



        //if (dic.ContainsKey((userInfo.ToUserId)))
            //Clients.Client(dic[userInfo.ToUserId].HubId).ObjBroadCastMessage(userInfo);            
    }              

    [HubMethodName("Notify")]
    public void Notify(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        UserInfo objUserInfo = new UserInfo();

        if (dic.ContainsKey(userInfo.UserId))
        {
            Clients.Caller.differentName();
        }
        else
        {
            UserDetail objUserDetail = new UserDetail();
            objUserDetail.HubId = userInfo.HubId;

            dic.TryAdd(userInfo.UserId, objUserDetail);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, UserDetail> entry in dic)
            {
                Clients.Caller.online(entry.Key);
            }

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
                new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            Clients.Others.enters(jSearializer.Serialize(UserBAL.GetUser(Convert.ToInt32(userInfo.UserId))));
        }

        objUserInfo.UserOnlineStatus(Convert.ToInt32(userInfo.UserId), true);
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        UserInfo objUserInfo = new UserInfo();

        var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.HubId == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());            

        UserDetail s;
        if (name.Key != null && dic.ContainsKey(name.Key))
        {
            dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);

            objUserInfo.UserOnlineStatus(Convert.ToInt32(name.Key), false);

        }

        return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
    }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    private string hubId = string.Empty;
    private string callStatus = "0";//1: Accepted; 2:Rejected; 3:Busy

    public string HubId { get { return hubId; } set { hubId = value; } }
    public string CallStatus { get { return callStatus; } set { callStatus = value; } }
}

public class VideoCall
{
    private string userId = string.Empty;
    private string toUserId = string.Empty;
    private string callStatus = string.Empty;//1: Accepted; 2:Rejected; 3:Busy

    public string UserId { get { return userId; } set { userId = value; } }
    public string ToUserId { get { return toUserId; } set { toUserId = value; } }
    public string CallStatus { get { return callStatus; } set { callStatus = value; } }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    private string hubId = string.Empty;
    private string userId = string.Empty;
    private string toUserId = string.Empty;
    private string userName = string.Empty;
    private string message = string.Empty;
    private string subscriberToken = string.Empty;
    private bool isVideoCall = false;
    private string publisherSessionId = string.Empty;
    private string email = string.Empty;
    private string profilePicture = string.Empty;
    private string send = string.Empty;
    private string isFirstTime = string.Empty;
    private string callStatus = "0";//1: Accepted; 2:Rejected; 3:Busy

    public string HubId { get { return hubId; } set { hubId = value; } }
    public string UserId { get { return userId; } set { userId = value; } }
    public string ToUserId { get { return toUserId; } set { toUserId = value; } }
    public string UserName { get { return userName; } set { userName = value; } }
    public string Message { get { return message; } set { message = value; } }
    public string SubscriberToken { get { return subscriberToken; } set { subscriberToken = value; } }
    public bool IsVideoCall { get { return isVideoCall; } set { isVideoCall = value; } }
    public string PublisherSessionId { get { return publisherSessionId; } set { publisherSessionId = value; } }
    public string Email { get { return email; } set { email = value; } }
    public string ProfilePicture { get { return profilePicture; } set { profilePicture = value; } }
    public string Send { get { return send; } set { send = value; } }
    public string IsFirstTime { get { return isFirstTime; } set { isFirstTime = value; } }
    public string CallStatus { get { return callStatus; } set { callStatus = value; } }

    public void UserOnlineStatus(int userId,bool isOnline)
    {            
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChatAppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateOnlineStatus", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsOnline", isOnline);

            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.